# ClearCase hijack functionality in subversion

Tags: svn, clearcase

Is there a way to "hijack" a file in subversion like there is in ClearCase. Googling so far has not given me a definitive answer. For non ClearCase users Hijacking a file means temporarily removing it from version control.

Comment: Info on Hijacked files: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.doc/topics/c_hijack.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVN operates on a "copy-modify-merge" model, meaning it's always possible to make local modifications to your working copy, without needing to "lock" or "hijack" it.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.basic.vsn-models.html#svn.basic.vsn-models.copy-merge.sb-1

Comment: Thank you. I thought thats how it worked but like I said in the OP I couldn't find something saying what you did.

Answer (score 2):

ClearCase has an odd mix of [optimistic lock and pessimistic lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949936/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reserved-checkout-and-an-unreserved-checkout/2950583#2950583).
But hijacking a file (for snapshot view) or eclipsing a file (for dynamic view) concerns only private changes (i.e. changes done without telling ClearCase first).

As David mentions, SVN doesn't follow that model: you modify first, and then tell SVN during the commit step, which will include *all* files modified.
ClearCase has not a "workspace wide revision", only a file-by-file commit.