# SVN Hijack a configuration file

Tags: svn, clearcase

I need the clearcase's hijack functionality in svn. I need this to change **ONLY LOCALY** some configuration files.
How to do this preventing the commit from all users?
Thanks

Comment: Possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951032/svn-ignore-without-deleting-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClearCase hijack functionality in subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129637/clearcase-hijack-functionality-in-subversion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have administrator privileges, you can define a new property, say `site:nocommit`. When set, you can have your pre-commit hook reject this file.

Personally, I think this is much better than "silent" solutions suggested by others.

Comment: It can be a nuisance for everyone to have to remember to not commit the config files.  I would rename the config file in version control to something like foo.config.default and have everyone use a local copy (non version controlled and svn:ignored) for the true foo.config

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to use symbolic links.
The link, especially the pointer to the local file is preserved, but not the content of the file. So the file content may differ on each local installation.

If needed you can combine this approach with a script installing some default files to the link destination to reflect the local differences of your environment.

[Documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.tour.cycle.html)