# dynamic and snapshot views in clearcase

Tags: view, clearcase, snapshot

I have been using clearcase snapshot views in my current project. so, it requires update to refresh content. does it mean any update I do on view is updated to the servers and any updates others do are updated to my view? . Also, If I  try to checkout a file in snapshot view which somebody else  has already checked out in his snapshot view  but not updated, will I succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does it mean any update I do on view is updated to the servers?

Only if you do a cleartool checkin (commit the new version of the files you were working on after a checkout)

> and any updates others do are updated to my view?

Only if you do a cleartool update (a refresh of your snpashot view)

> If I try to checkout a file in snapshot view which somebody else has already checked out in his snapshot view but not updated, will I succeed?

You will if the other checkout was unreserved.
If it was a checkout reserved, you won't be able to checkout (but you will be able to hijack the file)

See:

- "[What is the difference between a reserved checkout and an unreserved checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950583/6309)"
- "[Identifying hijacked files in a snapshot view](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123318)"

> Hijacking an element in a snapshot view involves making it writable and making a change to it.

Comment: in my last question if someone else has checked out  a file but I have not done an update  and try to checkout, how will it not allow me to go ahead with reserved checkout?

Comment: @user2636464 if the checkout was reserved, then: a/ an update of your view will *not* erase your current modification, but b/ you won't be able to checkout the file (you will have to wait for the other to checkin first)

Comment: If I checkout in snapshot view, how does it know that the file is already checked out when I have not done an update?

Comment: @user2636464 if the file is already checkout reserved, you will know it immediately because your checkout will fail. If it is checked out unreserved or if it is not checkout, then your checkout will succeed. To be sure, a lsvtree (version tree) will confirm if the file is checked out or not by another view.

Comment: so I will come to know even if i have not updated my snapshot view ?

Comment: @user2636464 I generally keep a dynamic view with the same config spec than my snapshot view: a version tree on a file in that dynamic view would show if there is a checkout (reserved or unreserved) in another view.

Comment: thanks. But how about my snapshot view . will it show checkout in another view for the file?

Comment: @user2636464 I don't remember if the version tree would show it without a `cleartool update`. That is why I kept a dynamic view. At least this one is *always* up-to-date (since it is dynamic).