# ClearCase: I am not able to get the files from Clearcase

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearquest

I'm using the ClearCase as version control tool.
When I am creating view in a particular VOB, all the folders has been downloaded from the server. But files are not getting downloaded.

For that I am doing as a workaround a 'checkout' of the current vob and then UNDO checkout the same. Then only I am getting files.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Is it a dynamic or snapshot view?

Comment: What is your OS where you create your view? And what is the OS of the ClearCase server? What is its version?

Comment: Windows7, its on windows server, CC version:

Version: 8.0.1

Comment: OK. What do you think of my old answer below? Are you working in a dynamic or snapshot view?

Comment: i tried the below answer, its not getting the file. i'm working in snapshot view

Comment: What the `cleartool ls` return? I mentioned it in order to have some clues as to why your file is *not* downloaded

Comment: currently i'm using clearcase team explorer. can you tell me where do i need to execute the cleartool ls?

Comment: In a command line (CMD), in the parent folder of the missing file.

Comment: i got the error msg like ;'cleartool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Adjust your PATH (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11992799/6309): `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Rational\ClearCase\bin`

Comment: yeah...i did ,, one more clue is while creating the view ".cc_loading" folder is not getting created.

Comment: OK, cc_loader means ClearTeam explorer, and possibly web views, not snpashot views. See more at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21696313

Comment: If this is a web view, and if "cleartool" doesn't work, it may very well be one, rcleartool.bat in the same directory as the ctexplorer.ini. You can use it to do "rcleartool update" and see if you get any useful error messages. rcleartool ls should work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all the folders has been downloaded from the server.

"Downloaded" means probably this is a [ClearCase snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31964555/6309), which reads the **[config spec](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm)**:

- "selection rules"
- "loading rules"

and download the elements (files and directories) whose version matches the selection rules, and whose path matches the loading rules.

You need to do a `cleartool ls` in a folder where you see only subfolders in order to understand what selection rules was used to download those folders (and not the files)

```
cd /path/to/my/view/(vobs/)myVob
cleartool ls
```

From there, you can edit the config spec ([`cleartool edcs`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_edcs.htm)) in order to fix the selection or loading rules, ensuring that folders *and files* are downloaded when you update the snapshot view.

Maybe those folders are [considered as hijacked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13279352/6309): see "[Locating hijacked files in snapshot views](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21118032)".

Answer (score 0):

If there is a .cc_loading directory it looks like a wev view. Cleartool claims that it doesn't work in those views (if if the command has nothing to do with a view context!).
You should you "rcleartool ls", but you can also see what version of the directory is used with the help of CTE.

I guess that you see version /main/0 of the directories.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a snapshot view, create a dynamic view with the same configspec and see what it sees. If you see directories and not files in the dynamic view, what is the configspec? And what does cleartool ls show you?