# I have ant script which works for clearcase. Can any one help me to convert it to GIT

Tags: git, ant, clearcase, clearcase-automation

I am migrating one application from clear case to GIT. A build script is written to increment build number and it is written with respect to clear case. And now I have to make it work for GIT. Anyone kindly help me to modify below code to make it work for GIT. 
I have changed the executable path to GIT.exe. So I just help to convert clear case commands to GIT.

```
<target name="decBuildNo">
    <trycatch property="exception">
        <try>
            <exec dir="${basedir}\calcBuild" executable="${cleartool}" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="update"/>
                <arg value="setenvs.bat"/>
            </exec>
            <!-- update the build number in setenvs.bat and check in-->
            <exec dir="${basedir}\calcBuild" executable="${cleartool}" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="co"/>
                <arg value="-c"/>
                <arg value="&quot;bump version number&quot;"/>
                <arg value="setenvs.bat"/>
            </exec>
            <decrbuild buildNumberKey="CALCMGR_BUILD_NO" fileName="${basedir}\calcBuild\setenvs.bat"/>
            <exec dir="${basedir}\calcBuild" executable="${cleartool}" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="ci"/>
                <arg value="-c"/>
                <arg value="&quot;bump version number&quot;"/>
                <arg value="setenvs.bat"/>
            </exec>
        </try>
        <catch>
            <echo>Increment build number failed: ${exception}</echo>
            <antcall target="buildfailed"/>
            <fail>${exception}</fail>
        </catch>
    </trycatch>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent for:

- [`cleartool update`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm) would be [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) (provided the Git repository is already cloned)

If you really want to update only one file `setenvs.bat`, you would need:

```
git fetch
git checkout HEAD -- setenvs.bat
```

`git checkout` is *not* `cleartool checkout (co)`: it updates the file content, it does not "creates a writable copy".
See "[What is the difference between a reserved checkout and an unreserved checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950583/6309)", where I do compare it with Git.

- [`cleartool co -nc ...`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkout.htm): no need, a Git repository is in read/write locally. There is no "`cleartool checkout`" needed.
- [`cleartool ci`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkin.htm): you would need to add, commit and push

That  is:

```
git add setenvs.bat
git commit -m "bump version number"
git push
```

See more on the difference between ClearCase and Git in

- "[What are the basic ClearCase concepts every developer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645771/6309)" (March 2009)
- "[ClearCase advantages/disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074785/6309)"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try and let you know the result. Can you please let me know what to do with the line. <arg value="&quot;bump version number&quot;"/> do I need to change it ?

Comment: @jon : no, it is the comment you add to your git commit (to record the change). I have edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Kindly help me with this error :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786767/ant-script-failing-with-error-source-file-does-not-exist-despite-the-file-exis